# Reactjs - Move to next page after login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, authentication

I'm new to react and I'm trying to make a small program.
I have a react based client, my server is running on Nodejs and my db is Postgres.

I managed to make a working login from the client with auth from the server.
How can I show a new page after a login has been successful?

my app.js:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { url } = this.props.match

return (
  <div className="fx-row high">
      <Sidebar url={ url }/>
    <div className="page fx-col fx-grow" style = {{ width : 150, height : 150, marginLeft : 450, marginTop : 100}}>

      <Switch>
        <Route path={ url + 'demo' } component={ Demo }/>
        <Route path={ url + 'audits' } component={ Audits }/>
        <Route component={ Login }/>

      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In My login I have a handleSubmit which sends a post with parameters to the server and get the response body.
I want that after handltSubmit get the correct response, to show a different screen from the login, lets say just a screen that says "You are logged in" for now.

Thank you

Comment: When I'm trying to import { browserHistory} from 'react-router'
I get an error 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

return (
  <div className="fx-row high">
      <Sidebar url={ url }/>
    <div className="page fx-col fx-grow" style = {{ width : 150, height : 150, marginLeft : 450, marginTop : 100}}>

      <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/demo' component={ Demo }/>
            <Route path='/audit' component={ Audits }/>
            <Route path='/SiteMange' component={ SiteManage }/>
            <Route path='/' component={ Login }/>
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In your `Login` component you can call `push` method of `history` object that you will get as `props` in your routed page.

so on login success call the following method to redirect to your next route. For example say `home` page.

`this.props.history.push('SiteMange')`

Comment: Thanks, now this is my app.js :https://pastebin.com/4PXSgSF8 and after login the browser address changes to http://localhost:9191/#/SiteMange but I still see the same page. I have a SiteManage component that I built

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using fetch for server request you could do the following:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(your code here)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if ( data.user ) {
            this.props.history.push("home"); // in this case I use home as your path name
        } else {
            Some actions here
        }
     });
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I still have a problem : the browser address changes to localhost:9191/#/SiteManage (SiteManage is my 'main') but I still see the same page. I have a SiteManage component that I built